# how do i integrate This function using sympy and scipy.quad?

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

This is the function below. I want to integrate it with respect of x.

```
z = (((x**2)-4*x+5*y)/4*x )
integral= sp.integrate(z,x).simplify()
print (integral)
```

This code is showing wrong ans. how do I solve this?

Comment: Aren't you missing a parenthesis around `4*x` at the end?

Comment: Use a sympy integration.  Don't try to use sympy in scipy functions

Comment: simpy is the wrong tag, simpy is a discreate event simulation package